# Polite way to ask salary

Tags: questions, politeness, email

I'd like to know what is the most polite way to ask a university director/coordinator in a email how much is the stipend/salary of a graduate program.

Thank you very much!

Comment: That question (the one you're asking us, not the one you want to ask the director) is huge. If you want to get a response to an email, the entire email has to be polite, not just the part of the email where you ask the question, and email etiquette is a huge topic. It depends on who you're sending to, whether or not you know that person, whether that person ranks above you, when you're sending the email, and many other factors. This question is probably more relevant to academia.stackexchange.com, and even they would require _much_ more detail in order to answer it meaningfully.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I always worry very much if my emails are entirely polite, that's why I asked here only about that specific part, because that's the one I've been feeling confused about, especially because I'm not an English native speaker and I don't wanna write it incorrectly. If I send something like "I would like to know how much the stipend is" to the department, is it grammatically correct and acceptable? Again, thank you for your attention. :)

Comment: I think more information is needed -- in what country is this university; is the graduate program stipend one that is paid to someone for being a student, or is it associated with something like teaching that graduate students (at least in the US) are (or were) expected to do as a 'job' for which they got the stipend? I think we need to know an overall situation, including the culture you're dealing with.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response,  rcook! I plan to apply for a graduate program in the United States, and to be able to receive the stipend, the student has to work as a teaching or research assistant. :)